# Piston is powered without redstone?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-redstone

I have this problem with my redstone. Im trying to build a trapped chest piston trap, but 3 of the pistons will just not deactivate. it stays powered even when its not connected to anything. is there any way to stop this?[image: See? Its not connected to anything. What do i do?]

Comment: Is there a red stone torch on the back of the wall?

Comment: This has been answered before. http://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/116174/90489 http://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/226194/90489

Comment: Try updating the piston

Comment: In your particular case, I'm fairly certain that there is a solid block two blocks above the piston (behind the line of lamps) being powered.